# Is a plural nature of God the best explanation for the use of el, ĕlôha, and ĕlōhîm in Deuteronomy?

Tags: deuteronomy, soteriology, trinity

The vocabulary of Deuteronomy identifies God using three different words: *[el](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/h410/kjv/wlc/0-1/), [ĕlôha](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/h433/kjv/wlc/0-1/),* and *[ĕlōhîm](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/h430/kjv/wlc/0-1/)*. *el* and *ĕlôha* are singular; *ĕlōhîm* is plural.

There are even passages where two different words are used together:

> *el* and *ĕlōhîm*
> For the LORD your God (*ĕlōhîm*) is God (*ĕlōhîm*) of gods (*ĕlōhîm*) is God (*ĕlōhîm*) of gods (*ĕlōhîm*), and Lord of lords, a great God (*el*) a mighty, and a terrible, which regardeth not persons, nor taketh reward (Deuteronomy 10:17 KJV)

> *ĕlôha* and *ĕlōhîm*
> They sacrificed unto devils, not to God (*ĕlôha*) to gods (*ĕlōhîm*) whom they knew not, to new *gods* that came newly up, whom your fathers feared not. (Deuteronomy 32:17)

Deuteronomy has the portion of the Shema stating God, *ĕlōhîm*, is one:

> <sup>4</sup> Hear, O Israel: The LORD our God *ĕlōhîm* is one LORD. <sup>5</sup> And thou shalt love the LORD thy God *ĕlōhîm* with all thine heart, and with all thy soul, and with all thy might. (Deuteronomy 6)

If there is one God one expects to find only one word to identify one God. Finding three words introduces ambiguity and is unnecessary. On the other hand, the oneness of God describing unity, follows the way these three words in Deuteronomy are used and understood.

The historical books, First and Second Kings and First and Second Chronicles use only *ĕlōhîm* to identify God. So it is possible to record the history of Israel using one word to identify God. Yet, Deuteronomy unnecessarily and intentionally uses three different words.

The New Testament describes a physical manifestation of God's redeeming work through the Son of God and the Spirit of God. The three words in Deuteronomy, two which are singular and one plural follow the pattern of the work of salvation.

Is the plural nature of God the best explanation for the use of *el, ĕlôha,* and *ĕlōhîm* in Deuteronomy? If not, what is a better explanation for the unnecessary and intentional uses of three different terms for God?

Comment: Jewish SE will be more suitable for this question

Comment: @RevelationLad. Is the trinity compose of 3 separate independent intelligent Beings?

Comment: @RevelationLad. Is the term God, the Trinitarian equivalent of God the father, God the Son, and God the Holy Spirit?

Comment: @AlexBalilo I think the best way to understand something is to focus on what the Bible says about that something. In this case the Bible is identifying God. The logical question is if God is one why does the text use different words? In contrast to Kings where God is identified with one word, why are three necessary? For example, why do we use one word? Why don’t we follow what the Bible says and rather then use one word, start identifying God with three different words.

Comment: @RevelationLad. Following uwhat the bible say would lead us to not believe what it does not say. Nothing is said about the trinity in the bible.

Comment: @AlexBalilo Exactly. Thus a god is impossible and God is how it is understood.

Comment: @RevelationLad. Your theory about the trinity /tripleness of God would be much stronger if  the Jews actually used the term..The trinity or the tripleness of God is not in the bible.

Comment: @RevelationLad. Arguably, your theory is in agreement with your theologically biased “head knowledge” of Scripture. Yet it is without any evidence that the Jews, or Christians ever applied that knowledge in the way you postulate. You have built a question about your theory which you have not fully explained, and provided no evidence from  Scripture. There is no record that plainly say with what you theorize.

Comment: @AlexBalilo Except I am asking about an aspect of God which is clearly present in the written text of Deuteronomy: why any writer would use **three** different words for one "God." How you "label" that is a matter of choice. I chose "tripleness." You may call it by some other term, but you should at least acknowledge what is present in the actual text, IMO.

Comment: @RevelationLad. What "aspect" of God is Deuteronomy talking about? You should at least clearly define trinity before postulating what is in the actual text. What is present in the actual text anyway, and how did the people at that time understand it? There is nothing plainly stated in the bible that say three different words for the bible mean trinity. What does trinity mean?

Comment: @AlexBalilo What aspect? That is my question. Rather than assault my question, why don’t you give your explanation why Deuteronomy requires three different words for one God? This is a reasonable question under any historical circumstances. But given the exclusive use of *elohim* in Kings and Chronicles, there is an added dimension. If other writers were determined to record history using one word for one God (as one would expect), then why does the second giving of the Law require three words?

Comment: @RevelationLad. You said that that aspect was "clearly" present. That is why I asked. If it is "clearly" present, why did you ask it? Without clearly defining trinity, how do you expect your postulation to  be assented? How is this "tripleness" of God compatible with the idea that there is only one God?

Comment: @AlexBalilo I believe using three different words is significant. How that significance is understood is the question. Based on the NT one explanation is the Father, the Son and the Spirit. Is there another explanation? That is the basis of my question.

Comment: @RevelationLad..You can say that it is "significant" but it still is not in the bible. Without clearly defining trinity, how do you expect your postulation to be assented? How is this "tripleness" of God compatible with the idea that there is only one God?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145333/discussion-between-revelation-lad-and-alex-balilo).

Comment: I would not have said anything more if you had not edited your "Deuterocanonical" 
discourse further, but now that you have, I, myself, feel compelled to say more, as a further rebuttal of your continued exoneration of what amounts to misplaced *allegory*, a lauding of all that's *mythical* even. 1. *El*, speaks to the root form of God and as such is lacking in *intensity* and consequently is used sparingly. 2. *Eloha*, is used in the "Song of Moses" and waxes *poetical* as a result. 3. *Elohim*, on the other hand, is the only **plural** form to describe God and is used 95% of the time..tbc..

Comment: ...ctd... When applying to Jehovah, *Elohim* is used as a plural of majesty, dignity, or excellence. **(Gen 1:1)**. Regarding this, Aaron Ember wrote: "That the language  of the OT has entirely given up the idea of plurality in ...[*Elohim*] (as applied to the God of Israel) is especially shown by the fact that it is almost invariably **construed with a singular verbal predicate, and takes a singular adjectival attribute** ... [*Elohim*] must rather be explained as an *intensive plural*, denoting *greatness* and *majesty*, being equal to The Great God."

Comment: @OldeEnglish “And *elohim* said, let us make man in out image and after our likeness…” plural word and plural verb. And why does the intensive plural lose that sense when it becomes a normal plural, gods, judges…and how is it that Moses finds *el* and *eloha* perfectly acceptable to describe this Great God? The question is why does Moses need to use three words when one is obviously all which is needed?

Comment: 1. **Gen,1:26a**, the first verb here (said), is specific to *Elohim* and is in the singular. Furthermore, at this point in the creation, God *(Elohim)* is not alone. Apart from the angels, we have the *Word of God*, the **only begotten** son. Ryrie, on the other hand regards the *Us ... Our*, as plurals of majesty, *intensive plurals* IOW. 2. The *intensive plural* only applies when relating to Jehovah. 3. Moses is not *definitively* accepting of *el* and *eloha* as being a description of "The **Great** God", only the distinct *majesty* of *Elohim* fits. 4. Your last sentence is *immaterial*.

Comment: @OldeEnglish The language, the text, and the subsequent behavior of the people all demonstrate the plural nature, a mystery revealed by the Christ who is the Son of God. All other explanations fail in the LXX and the NT.

Comment: "The New Testament describes a physical manifestation of God's redeeming work through the Son of God and the Spirit of God. The three words in Deuteronomy, two which are singular and one plural follow the pattern of the work of salvation." In what way?

Comment: @davidianwalker It was the Son who came, taught, died, was raised again, and returned. Each action was done by one who was visibly singular and therefore was correctly witnessed as such. IOW Son was on the cross. Son said *My God My God…* Yet from the beginning it was *Elohim* who said let us make man in our image and after our likeness. Regardless of how the plan was carried out it was *us* who did it because it it was *our* plan from before the foundation of the world.

Comment: Here's the short version : "The three words in Deuteronomy ... follow the pattern of the work of salvation." In what way?

Comment: @davidianwalker It was the Son of God who singularly died on the cross. It is the Spirit of God who singularly pours the love of God into a heart. Yet the plan from the beginning was always plural *Let **us** make man in **our** image and after **our** likeness.*

Comment: The elohim or aggelos are a multitude, so plural. What's your point?

Comment: @davidianwalker The plural is what is expected if God is Father, Son, Spirit. In fact, this is a much better explanation of why first person plural pronouns are used than the so called intensive plural, plural of majesties, or God discussing His pans with angels, or other spiritual beings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the triune nature of God which is present in the New Testament is correct, then it is a mystery. That is, the plural nature of God was hidden in the Old Testament until more fully explained in the New. In particular, the revelation was in the form of the Son of God.

> <sup>**1**</sup> Long ago, at many times and in many ways, God spoke to our fathers by the prophets, <sup>**2**</sup> but in these last days he has spoken to us by his Son, whom he appointed the heir of all things, through whom also he created the world. <sup>**3**</sup> He is the radiance of the glory of God and the exact imprint of his nature, and he upholds the universe by the word of his power. After making purification for sins, he sat down at the right hand of the Majesty on high, <sup>**4**</sup> having become as much superior to angels as the name he has inherited is more excellent than theirs. (Hebrews 1)

In the past, God (Father, Son, Spirit) spoke. In these last days He has spoken by His Son. What was hidden in the plural nature, was revealed and made purification for sins.

If this is true, we would expect God to describe himself in the Old Testament using both a plural and a singular world. This is in fact, exactly what the Hebrew text states.

The most common word is *ĕlōhîm* which is plural. Yet this fails to accurately convey the truth the Son of God will be sent. Therefore, *el* and *ĕlôha* are also used to describe God and His work.

Father, Son, Spirit are individually hidden in the sense the Hebrew is **unspecific** beyond stating God at times must be identified using a word which is not plural.

There are other explanation for *ĕlōhîm*. One is the intensive plural or plural of majesties. However, these may also be seen as selective interpretation, since the same word elsewhere is understood to mean something completely different. Furthermore, if God required a plural word to describe Himself, then, not only would any singular word would fall short; it would be derogatory.

> They sacrificed unto devils, not to God (*ĕlôha*) to gods (*ĕlōhîm*) whom they knew not, to new *gods* that came newly up, whom your fathers feared not. (Deuteronomy 32:17)

Moses is described as someone who spoke directly to God. If any person was in a position to understand the nature of God, it was Moses. Since Moses used three different words to describe God, he was using the Hebrew language in a way the New Testament explains: God, Father, Son, Spirit are one.

Therefore, understanding God's nature as plural is the best understanding of the vocabulary of Deuteronomy.

Comment: In due time, not too far off IMO, we, of the spiritual *persuasion*, will come to learn how valid and trustworthy, consequential even, our biblical belief tendencies have been, particularly when it came to imparting same on other, often less suspecting, spiritual seekers. We can only hope that our belief in the "Ransom Sacrifice", that the Son of God took it upon himself, in no uncertain terms, to account for the sins of mankind, holds more *sway*, than any other of our biblical interpretations, right or wrong, which we find ourselves, only to eager, to pass on.

Comment: "... the triune nature of God ..." The what now?

Comment: @OldeEnglish I encourage you to look for *truth* rather than *persuasion*. I encourage you to begin by believing what the Hebrew text states.

Answer (score 1):

Briefly, the answer is "no" for a very simple reason:  the writers of the Old Testament had no concept of a Trinity.  Writers do not make use of concepts of which they know nothing.  The earliest inkling of trinity in YHWH doesn't show up until late Second Temple Judaism, and then it's only speculative based on noting the "two powers" doctrine with an invisible YHWH always in heaven but a YHWH Who also walks on Earth in the form of a man plus how the Spirit of YHWH is sometimes treated as a person Who is plainly not either the heavenly YHWH or the one Who walks on Earth.

Comment: Then why did the writers use three different words, one of which is plural for God? For example, in Greek and in English, only one word is necessary. Yet in Hebrew one is insufficient, three are necessary. Absent a meaningful explanation, the issue is why Greek and English fail to preserve a distinction which is present in the Hebrew.

Comment: @RevelationLad  There really isn't a distinction in the Hebrew.  It's a case of using different words that mean the same thing.  An example in English would be walk/strolled/strode -- each of those words means to proceed on foot.

Comment: @RevelationLad 
Besides that, English has just one word, "God".
As for the plural, generally the word for God, אֱלֹהִ֔ים comes in the plural and just indicates YHWH; context can tell the difference.  As for   הָאֵ֨ל הַגָּדֹ֤ל, it could be a couple of different reasons; one is that the writer is just varying the vocabulary, others could be more pointed.

Comment: If the Scripture is inspired, why the need to vary something which does not vary?

Comment: @RevelationLad - A very apt explanation as to why the writers used three different words for God is given in Dottard's answer, which you, yourself, mistakenly, or was it conveniently, hid/deleted, due, it would seem, to its lack of support for the "Trinity" *doctrinal* belief.  As to the one *plural* form of God *(Elohim)* - *The American Journal of Semitic Languages and Literatures*, Vol. XXI, 1905, p. 208 - describes this plurality as an *intensive plural*, denoting *greatness* and *majesty*, being equal to The Great God. For the record, Dottard is a self confessed Trinitarian.

Comment: @OldeEnglish 1. Dottard’s answer was deleted by Dottard. 2. If in fact the plural is an intensive plural, why is the singular *eloha* used to identify God? In what way does God become more intensive (if the singular is the original term) or less intensive (if the plural is the original term)? 3. If the plural is an intensive what does the singular *el* say about the nature of God? What accounts for **three** different words used? The “intensive plural” explanation only serves to magnify the issue, because if the plural was the way to describe God, then it should be done so consistently….

Comment: … offering up an explanation for *elohim* which is contradicted by both *eloha* and *el* only serves to point out the issue. If God was so magnificent and indescribable that only the plural would do, then what accounts for the singular, which by definition is a lesser, and so inadequate term to identify God? OTOH, if the two singular terms are in fact able to indentfy God, then why is the plural ever necessary?

Comment: @RevelationLad - My apologies, for the apparent incorrect assumption as to who hid/deleted Dottard's answer. The caption above his answer said that it was removed by the OP (Original Poster), which I took to mean *initial* poster of the Q. Nevertheless, his answer -  which you and I are privileged to still be able to see, due to having surpassed the required number of "reputational" points (i.e. 2000) - would still seem to hold water as to any further entreaties you may still have. I, for one, do not feel any need to expound on what I've already said, or indeed pointed to.

Comment: @OldeEnglish His answer is much like the “intensive plural.” Rather than treat the exactual text for what it say, we invent explanations. But those explanations do not agree with how all the words are used or even the plural use. On one hand it is an intensive plural and in the next verse it’s a normal plural. All the while maintaining there is one God who seemingly cannot decide on how He should be identified. Is God confused or does it mean exactly what it says?

Comment: @RevelationLad  Why would an inspired writer not use the vocabulary available to him?  Do you think that inspiration made the writers dimwitted, or that inspiration is supposed to make the scripture dull?

Comment: @OldeEnglish   That's a very old reference and despite the popularity of that explanation it is no longer considered valid.  Hebrew has a number of words that are plural in form but used in the singular -- "water" and "face" are common examples.  It also has words which can be used in either singular or plural, such as :life".

Comment: @RevelationLad   God didn't write it, a human did.  God doesn't dictate words very often; when He does the scriptures tell us so.  Nor does He take over the writers' minds; that's what demons do.
You seem to be making a theological argument to decide how to translate something.  That's backwards; theology comes from the text, and the text comes from the language.  In this case, there's nothing unique about the language.

Comment: Deuteronomy was written by Moses. Scripture says Moses spoke directly to God. If Moses chooses different words to describe what was said, I think the words should be considered accordingly. When three different words are translated as "God" without even a footnote alerting the reader to different words in the original text, it is the translation which is attempting to impose a theological position which is inconsistent with the literal text.

Answer (score -1):

Hebrew writers, in a similar manner to English writers today, liked to vary their wording and make it less repetitive where possible.  The Tetragrammaton, YHWH, is an interesting example of this.  It is God's name, but also occurs in shortened form.  For readers of the KJV, the only verse in which this shortened form is apparent is Psalm 68:4.

> Sing unto God, sing praises to his name: extol him that rideth upon
> the heavens by his name JAH [Hebrew: יָ֥הּ], and rejoice before him.
> (Psalm 68:4, KJV)

However, the shortened form occurs in dozens of verses, including in Exodus, Psalms, and Isaiah.  This is not thought to be a separate name for God, but simply an abbreviated form, used more especially in poetic passages for variety or for its poetic value.

In Deuteronomy, as noted in the question, there are multiple variations on "elohim."  Deuteronomy 5:12 is of special interest, as it combines "Yahweh" (יְהוָ֥֣ה/YHWH) with "אֱלֹהֶֽ֗יךָ/eloheka"--a singular form of "elohim" along with the pronominal suffix for "your".

> Keep the sabbath day to sanctify it, as the LORD (יְהוָ֥֣ה) thy God
> (אֱלֹהֶֽ֗יךָ) hath commanded thee. (Deuteronomy 5:12, KJV)

If Yahweh (YHWH), undisputedly the sacred name of God, is singular, and is coupled, as here, with a singular form for "elohim," the Bible would be contradicting itself to also teach that Yahweh were plural.

"Elohim" itself, when used for Yahweh and not for additional or other beings, such as for the pagan gods or for angels or judges, is always accompanied by singular verb forms or singular adjectives, showing that it is grammatically singular, despite its plural word form.  Hebrew uses many words which appear plural but whose number is shown to be singular by the verbs or adjectives associated with it.  Some Hebrew nouns do not even have a "singular" form, like "news" in English which always appears plural in form but is used with singular verbs.

Some scholars, including professors at Hebrew University, believe that "elohim" is a loan word from Aramaic, the speakers of Aramaic having been polytheistic and always having used it in a plural form.  Proponents of this theory suggest the Hebrews would not have encountered a singular form of the word, but simply applied singular verbs and adjectives to it.

Independent of the origin of "elohim" itself, some scholars also claim that the shortened or singular forms of the noun may have actually been *names* of other (heathen) gods, which is why they are so seldom used for the true God.

Dr. Eli Lizorkin-Eyzenberg, a Christian Jew and a professor at Hebrew University, is a Trinitarian who teaches that there is no support from the Hebrew or Greek of the Bible for the Trinity doctrine, but claims that we believe in the Trinity today because the light has grown since Bible times.  He likens the Trinity dogma to slavery as an example, as even in the New Testament times, slavery was still honored--yet Christians today nearly universally oppose the practice.

Honest Trinitarians will admit that the Bible has no direct support for the dogma; neither in Hebrew, nor in the Greek.  The word "elohim" is no exception.  Elohim is so clearly used in singular form whenever used for the true God that it is almost beyond question.  The uses of "eloha" or "el"--singular and shortened forms of the noun--do not vary from this.

### Conclusion

The various implementations of "elohim" in shortened or singular forms do not lend support for any suggestion of a plurality or "tripleness" within the Godhead.  Regardless of which word may be used, whenever the word is applied to the true God, its verbs and adjectives consistently indicate that it is singular.  Multiple verses expressly indicate a singular God via other word forms, such as singular pronouns (e.g. Exodus 20:2-3) associated with God's name.

Comment: (-1) 1. The question is not about YHVH. 2. You state: "Hebrew writers, in a similar manner to English writers today, liked to vary their wording and make it less repetitive where possible." Perhaps with other terms but clearly not the case with the words in this question. *Elohim* is used 10 times more often then *el* and 50 more often then *ĕlôha*. Also *elohim* is used exclusively in 1 and 2 Kings, 1 Chronicles and with one exception, exclusive in 2 Chronicles.

Comment: @RevelationLad The scribes who are recording official records cannot be expected to write in the same style as others; thus I find it unsurprising that shortened forms are absent from the Kings and Chronicles.

Comment: Variation in style is one thing. Using a different word to describe the same thing is not stylistic.